# C reading bit by bit from char pointer

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a pointer

```
char *result
```

where my linked assembly program writes some data.
I now want to read the data bit by bit from the pointer.
I also know the length of the written data in bit, since my assembly program returned that value.
Is there an easy way to doing this or do i need to interpret it as chars and then bit-shift 8 times per char?

Comment: Process it bit-by-bit, or 8 bits at a time.

Answer (score 2):

This may be slightly faster than processing it bit-by-bit if the data is very long, by avoiding bit-shifting for all the bytes except the last one, as well as caching:

```
void process(const char* start, size_t bitlen, void (*f)(char)){
    int i, k;
    register char b;
    for (i = 0; i < bitlen / 8; i++){
        b = start[i];
        f(b & 1);
        f(b & 2);
        f(b & 4);
        f(b & 8);
        f(b & 16);
        f(b & 32);
        f(b & 64);
        f(b & 128);
    }
    b = start[i];
    for (k = 0; k < bitlen % 8; k++){
        f((b>>=1) & 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are platforms that have chars consisting of more than 8 bits.

Comment: just to be sure: replace the 8 calls to f with a single loop: ` int j; for (j=0;j<CHAR_BIT;j++) f(start[i] & 1<<j); `  CHAR_BIT is defined in limits.h

Comment: @Tommylee2k That'd ruin my whole idea of avoiding bitshifting every bit.

Comment: use -O3 and trust your compiler ;-)

Comment: There are at least two bugs in the code above: (1) it doesn't treat the last byte the same as the other bytes - the last byte is passed `0` or `1`  depending on the corresponding bit, but the unrolled part used for the other bytes passes `0` or `1 << pos` for each bit where `pos` is the byte position. For example, for the value 0x7, the unrolled part will pass `1, 2, 4, 0, 0, ...` but the final part (ignoring bug 2) will pass `1, 1, 1, 0, 0, ...`.

Comment: Bug (2) is that the `f((b>>=1) & 1);` part in the final loop skips the LSB bit, since the shift happens first, dropping the first bit. You probably want `f(b & 1); b >>= 1;` in the loop body.

Comment: @Tommylee2k I would trust `-Ofast -march=native` more :)